# Is there a way to keep all instances of certain podcasts on iTunes while only keeping the unplayed instances of other podcasts?

Tags: ipod, podcasts

Using the latest iTunes, is there any way I can take one particular podcast and say that I want everything that is on iTunes for that podcast to always be on my iPod?

For others, I just want the unplayed one on my iTunes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure to mark those podcasts as keep.

Comment: i dont follow this ??

Comment: I believe the default setting is to delete all listened to podcasts. You need to change the setting on each podcast you want to keep to not automatically delete the listened to show.

I don't have iTunes here at work, so I can't clarify any more until I am in front of iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Set up a SmartPlaylist that lists the title or artist of the podcast.  Sync that playlist to the iPod.